# Copy/clone an Excel shape with EPPlus?

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

Is it possible to create a copy/clone of a shape in an Excel worksheet using the EPPlus library?

I know I can get an existing object with

```
var shapeExisting = ws.Drawings["ShapeName"];
```

(`ws` being the Worksheet object)

and a create new shape with

```
var shapeNew = ws.Drawings.AddShape("NewName", eShapeStyle.RtTriangle);
```

However, I'm unable to find a way to clone `shapeExisting`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there's no built-in functionality, so until I find a better solution, I added the following method to `EPPlus\Drawings\ExcelDrawings.cs`

```
public ExcelShape CloneShape(string SourceName, string TargetName)
{
    if ( _drawingNames.ContainsKey(TargetName.ToLower()))
    {
        throw new Exception("Target name already exists in the drawings collection");
    }

    if (!_drawingNames.ContainsKey(SourceName.ToLower()))
    {
        throw new Exception("Source shape does not exist in the drawings collection");
    }

    ExcelShape shape = new ExcelShape(this, this._drawingsXml,
                               (ExcelShape) this[SourceName]);
    shape.Name = TargetName;
    _drawings.Add(shape);
    _drawingNames.Add(TargetName.ToLower(), _drawings.Count - 1);
    return shape;
}
```

and also this constructor in `ExcelShape.cs`:

```
internal ExcelShape(ExcelDrawings drawings, XmlDocument DrawingsXml, ExcelShape shapeSource) :
            base(drawings, shapeSource._topNode.Clone(), "xdr:sp/xdr:nvSpPr/xdr:cNvPr/@name")

{
     this.init();
     XmlNode colNode = DrawingsXml.SelectSingleNode("//xdr:wsDr", NameSpaceManager);             
     colNode.AppendChild(this._topNode);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution to clone a shape with the current version of EPPlus (5.2.0) which i like to post here for anyone who is interested:

```
var clonedShape = 
     ws.Drawings.AddShape(
         "NewName",
         ws.Drawings["ShapeName"].As.Shape
     );
```