# Copy/clone an Excel shape with EPPlus to other worksheet?

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

Is it possible to create a copy/clone of a shape to an **other** Excel worksheet using the EPPlus library?

There is already a solution within the same Excel worksheet shown here: [Copy/clone an Excel shape with EPPlus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18380656/copy-clone-an-excel-shape-with-epplus)

But I need the possibility to copy it to an other worksheet (from a template to the destination). Does anyone know a workaround for that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found a solution for this problem.
I added this code to ExcelDrawings.cs file:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Add a new shape to the worksheet
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Name">Name</param>
    /// <param name="Source">Source shape</param>
    /// <returns>The shape object</returns>

    public ExcelShape AddShape(string Name, ExcelShape Source)
    {
        if (Worksheet is ExcelChartsheet && _drawings.Count > 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Chart worksheets can't have more than one drawing");
        }
        if (_drawingNames.ContainsKey(Name))
        {
            throw new Exception("Name already exists in the drawings collection");
        }
        XmlElement drawNode = CreateDrawingXml();
        drawNode.InnerXml = Source.TopNode.InnerXml;

        ExcelShape shape = new ExcelShape(this, drawNode);
        shape.Name = Name;
        shape.Style = Source.Style;
        _drawings.Add(shape);
        _drawingNames.Add(Name, _drawings.Count - 1);
        return shape;
    }
```